# busybox regular expression for group of IP addresses

Tags: regular-expression, busybox, ip-address

I need to be able to validate a group of IP addresses that will appear in a file that looks like this:

IP_SUBNETS=['10.1.111.0','10.2.111.0','10.2.123.0']

I'd like to write a regular expression that will allow n number of ip addresses, as long as they are delimited by "," and have single quotes around them, and the entire "list" is opened and closed by square brackets.

I've been able to find some bash examples of regular expressions but I'm having a hard time finding something that works for busybox.

so far this is what i have:

```
grep IP_SUBNETS myfile | cut -c 12- | grep '^\[[0-9].'
```

But i can't seem to get the grouping right.  aka one group per subnet.

**EDIT 1**

```
#!/bin/sh
iplist=['10.112.123.0'] 
pass="$(echo $iplist | grep -E '^\[(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3},)*([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\]$'"
echo "$pass"
```

Comment: kind of confused why you're grepping for IP_SUBNETS twice

Comment: what exactly is your input & output here? are you validating that the "IP_SUBNETS" line contains (any) list of syntactically correct IP's? Or that it contains *given* IPs?

Comment: @JeffSchaller sorry, you're right.  that was a typo as i was writing this post. And good question.  I just need to ensure that the list contains any legit IP address.  aka. syntax check vs. the specific addresses listed in my example above.

Comment: You need to quote $iplist — `pass="$(echo "$iplist" | grep -E …` also you have a missing ) at the end before the close "

Comment: @derobert I'm afraid that doesn't change the error message.

Comment: @derobert yeah i saw that too.  that was the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works here:

```
busybox grep -E '^\[(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3},)*([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\]$'
```

(busybox isn't my default grep, hence the "busybox" prefix).

That should *mostly* validate your list, though it isn't perfect. E.g., it'll accept `300.1.2.4` as a valid IP address. The regexp to *fully* validate that four dot-separated numbers represent a valid subnet start address would be much more complicated.

To break it down: First, note that part of it is repeated. Call that `I` for a second. Then you can see it's `^\[(I,)*I\]$` which gets you your comma-separated list of `I`s, with brackets around the entire list. If you then look at what `I` is, it's `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` which is simpler if you notice another repeated pattern, `O = [0-9]{1,3}`. It's then `(O.){1,3}O` ... which is your four decimal-separated octets. In a shell script, you can of course use variables to build the pattern from these simpler building blocks—a great aid to readability and maintainability.

I tested with the following test data (with expected result as a comment, not actually in the test data file):

```
1.2.3.4                          # bad: no brackets
[1.2.3.4]                        # good
[1.2.3.44]                       # good
[1.2.3.4                         # bad: missing bracket
1.2.3.4]                         # bad: missing bracket
[1.2.3.4,]                       # bad: empty item
[1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8]                # good
[1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8,]               # bad: empty item
[1.2.3.4,5.6.7.E]                # bad: E is not a number
[1.2.3.4,,5.6.7.8]               # bad: empty item
[1.2.3.1234]                     # bad: 1234 is more than 3 digits
```

edit: you could use `O = ([0-9]{1,2}|[0-1][0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` — there may be a simpler way to write that, not sure — to only take numbers 0–255; that leads to a much longer pattern:

```
busybox grep -E '^\[((([0-9]{1,2}|[0-1][0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]{1,2}|[0-1][0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),)*(([0-9]{1,2}|[0-1][0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]{1,2}|[0-1][0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\]$'
```

... which may or may not be worth it, depending on how important it is to fully validate them.